# Error Registering Plugin/Workflow Dll "Plugin type could not be found in the specified assembly"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm attempting to update a plugin within CRM 2011 On Prem, and the Plugin Registration Tool is returning this warning:

```xml
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ErrorCode>-2147204720</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Plugin type could not be found in the specified assembly.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2013-12-24T18:26:45.3112774Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147204720</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Plugin type could not be found in the specified assembly.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2013-12-24T18:26:45.3112774Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Is there a way to determine what the Plugin Type that could not be found in the specified assembly is?

### Edit

Did decompile the microsoft dll.  Looks like I could write a program, given the two dlls, which would lookup all of the plugin types in one dll, and attempt to load them in the other dll.  With some proper error handling, I'd be able to figure out the type that is missing.

```cs
internal Type GetPluginTypeType(PluginAssembly parentAssembly, PluginType typeEntity)
{
  int num = (int) ((BusinessEntity) parentAssembly).get_Item("sourcetype");
  Assembly assembly;
  if (num == 0)
  {
    if (((BusinessEntity) parentAssembly).IsAttributeNull("content"))
      throw new CrmException("Assembly content should not be null or empty.", -2147204719);
    assembly = PluginAssemblyFactory.LoadAssembly(Convert.FromBase64String((string) ((BusinessEntity) parentAssembly).get_Item("content")));
  }
  else if (num == 1)
    assembly = PluginAssemblyFactory.LoadAssembly((string) ((BusinessEntity) parentAssembly).get_Item("path"));
  else if (num == 2)
    assembly = Assembly.Load(PluginAssemblyFactory.FormatAssemblyName((string) ((BusinessEntity) parentAssembly).get_Item("name"), new Version((string) ((BusinessEntity) parentAssembly).get_Item("version")), (string) ((BusinessEntity) parentAssembly).get_Item("culture"), (string) ((BusinessEntity) parentAssembly).get_Item("publickeytoken"), CacheSolutionHelper.GetCustomizationLevel((IBusinessEntity) parentAssembly) == 0));
  else
    throw new CrmException(string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Unknown source type {0}.", new object[1]
    {
      (object) num
    }), -2147200995);
  if (assembly == (Assembly) null)
    throw new CrmException("Assembly could not be loaded.", -2147204719);
  Type type = assembly.GetType((string) ((BusinessEntity) typeEntity).get_Item("typename"));
  if (type == (Type) null)
    throw new CrmException("Plugin type could not be found in the specified assembly.", -2147204720);
  else
    return type;
}
```

Comment: did you change the signature?

Comment: @GuidoPreite the dll contains 35 different workflow activities. I don't believe I've changed any of the signatures (base class / Name / Worflow parameters). I did reference a couple new dlls, but I've added them to the gac. Is it really that hard to figure out what plugin type is actually broken?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I've found to determine which one is missing is to import the 'broken' plugin assembly into a sandboxed environment where you can see what gets imported. Then check to see if anything is different between the two. Sometimes you'll find that you renamed something and just didn't notice.

Other than that short of checking the GUIDs it is incredibly difficult.